# open async socket in perl that can somehow pause and resume perl script

Tags: perl, websocket

I have perl script that I want to open a socket in it  , so I can send some kind of message through it to the perl script so the perl script will pause / resume per request.
I tried using the IO::Async module from CPAN , but the installation keeps failing for me.
anyone has other suggestions ?

thanks.

Comment: If it receives a pause command, how will it read the socket to see a resume command?

Comment: Pausing could mean to stop working on a task and listen for a resume command.

Comment: @capfan that's great solution , do you think of a way of doing it ?

Comment: @Mojo I'm not familiar with IO::Async or AnyEvent::Handle. But I did work with POE or Windows threads in the past. This page helped me to understand how to change my code to allow to listen to a resume command: http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook/Looping It basically says that you should break up your loops. Not sure, if this is a solution to your issue. On the level of the operating system, I think it's also possible to pause a running process and let it continue afterwards. However, I did not try to do such a thing yet.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [AnyEvent::Handle](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-7.12/lib/AnyEvent/Handle.pm) for async reads.